# Can we encourage our test team to collaborate with developers on automating tests?

Tags: c#, testing, test-automation

I am a `C#` developer, and my team and I are trying to start `automated functional tests`. *(Note that we don't want to do `Unit Tests`; we expect to develop tests which test one function point per test)*

Our software has several modules, but they have something in common: one input (can be File, string or database row) and some outputs (a file, a database row, or both in some cases).

One problem is that the configuration is stored in the database, and there is A LOT of configuration to enable the software to run correctly, and someone could change it and affect the tests.

In my opinion, we have an amazing Test team, and I'm thinking of finding a way where the developers could develop the tests but the Test team would sometimes help developing them too.

- The Test team develops the automated tests based on their test cases - is that a good approach?
- I know that if the creation of the test scenarios is hard to do, then the Test team will not see any reward. So, what's a good approach (in `C#`) to develop automated tests where both teams (development and test) could help to improve them?

Comment: As a tester, I want to get and run the software in two scriptable steps, so that I can rapidly develop tests without wasting hours on configuration. How difficult is that for your testers right now? All the test cases in the world don't matter when running them is an arduous, manual process. The best things devs can do is to see testers as users of the system, and implement necessary testability features. While best designed from the start, adding testability later can still be valuable (but takes more effort). What is the estimated ROI for increasing test coverage? Prioritize accordingly.

Comment: Use unit tests for basic core functionality of components (NUnit, MbUnit, etc). Use robot style tests for front end components (Selenium, etc). Your code base should take as much of the arduous nature out of testing. Your testers can still apply other exploratory tests, but the core functionality should have a reasonable coverage of unit and system tests written that can be automated, as part of your build/release process. The tests should match the requirements and every requirement should be covered by at LEAST one test.

Answer (score 2):

As a developer, I suppose that developers can certainly help testers to *implement* the automation of their tests.

I believe, however, it is best to leave the testers *scope*, *plan*, and *design* their test environment *and* test cases by and for themselves, without developer bias.

Separation of concerns. Segregation of responsibility.

'HTH,

Comment: I think you understood a little bit wrong. The tests is from the developer team, who will help is the tests.but good answer ^^ +1

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) with [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin). It is based on idea that testers or business experts can write semi-formatted, human readable tests and then developers create bindings between those tests and the application. In ideal situation, the bindings will be generic enough, that the test cases can be written or change without developer involvement.

Comment: IIRC SpecFlow is the .NET equivalent of Cucumber. They would probably gain more acceptance using that.

Comment: Thank you by your answer, I have already took a look in IIRC SpecFlow (.Net equivalent of Cucumber), and until now this is the way that we will follow.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of configuration - well, you need to simplify that for reproducible results. That means setting up pre-configured packs (or profiles) of configuration settings that can be re-applied at any time.

Then you can develop a set of config that is consistent for your test team and allow them to reset things to a known baseline.

As for your question - aren't they what the test team does anyway? Have you asked them to collaborate with you to help you become better testers?

Answer (score 1):

You could adopt a library that breaks testing into two parts: the high level test logic and the low level implementation.

For example, [robot framework](http://www.robotframework.rog) lets you specify test cases using high level keywords. I've successfully worked on a team where developers implement the keywords (in python, though robot supports .net, java, and other languages), and the testers use these keywords to create their tests.

Not only is this a good way to leverage the skills of both testers and developers, it gives testers an opportunity for career growth because they can learn how to use a programming language to write their own keywords.

There are other frameworks that work in a similar fashion. Three that readily come to mind are [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/), [specflow](http://www.specflow.org/) (essentially, cucumber for .net), and [fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/).